# How can able to perform addition of array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, addition

expected output should be like  category ["Agri","water"] values of area should be [3,3]
    I have tried with removing duplicates in the category array if duplicate found then area addition should take place

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Joining Two Arrays</h1>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var twodim = new Array(); 
var category = ["Agri", "Agri","water"];
var area = [1, 2, 3];

               for (n = 0; n < category.length; n=n+1)
               {

               twodim.push([category[n],area[n]]);

               }

alert(twodim);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myChildren;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please show your full attempt? None of that code seems to be trying to do what you described.

Comment: what is "myChildren"?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right. But instead of arrays, use objects. Object require keys and easy to keys are easy ways to detect dupes. If the key exist then do the addition.

```js
var twodim = {}
var category = ["Agri", "Agri", "water"];
var area = [1, 2, 3];

for (var n = 0; n < category.length; n++) {
  if (twodim[category[n]] === undefined) {
    twodim[category[n]] = [category[n], area[n]]
  } else {
    twodim[category[n]][1] += area[n]
  }
}

function getAsArray(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function(item) {
    return obj[item];
  });
}
console.log(twodim, getAsArray(twodim))
```

Comment: How can i see the alerts of it

Answer (score 0):

I hope below solution is help to you.

You can also check this solution in [here](https://jsfiddle.net/d3yv7z30/)

```
var new_cate = new Array();
var new_area = new Array();
var category = ["Agri", "Agri","water"];
var area = [1, 2, 3];

               for (n = 0; n < category.length; n=n+1)
               {

                  var IsFlag = false;
                    for(i=0;i<new_cate.length;i++){

                    if(new_cate[i] == category[n])
                    {
                      new_area[i] += area[n];
                      IsFlag = true;
                    }
                  }
                                    if(!IsFlag)
                                    {
                      new_cate.push(category[n]);
                    new_area.push(area[n]);
                                    }


               }

 console.log(new_cate);
 console.log(new_area);
```